# for-each in xslt 1.0

Tags: xml

How to do for-each in xsl? I get it goes to each element but I would really appreciate an in dept example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `<xsl:for-each select= "database/sims/sim[simID = $callsimID]">` to `<xsl:for-each select= "/database/sims/sim[simID = $callsimID]">` to make sure you select the `sim` elements down from the document node `/`.

I would however define a key `<xsl:key name="sim" match="sims/sim" use="simID"/>` and use `<xsl:for-each select="key('sim', $callsimID)">`, that should be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward and you don't need `<xsl:for-each>` at all. Also, you really should modularize your stylesheet.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Customers</title>
         </head>
         <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="database" />
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="database">
     <table rules="all">
         <caption>Customers</caption>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="
            sims/sim[
               simID = current()/calls/call[
                  countryCodeOfOtherParty = '49' 
                  and areaCodeOfOtherParty = '31' 
                  and numberCodeOfOtherParty ='124567'
               ]/simID
            ]
         " />
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="sim">
      <tr>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="customerID" /></td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

where

```
sims/sim[
   simID = current()/calls/call[
      countryCodeOfOtherParty = '49' 
      and areaCodeOfOtherParty = '31' 
      and numberCodeOfOtherParty ='124567'
   ]/simID
]
```

unsurprisingly means *"every SIM that has a call to that particular number"*.  Note the use of the `current()` function to reference the `<database>` in mid-XPath.

You can improve performance by using an `<xsl:key>`, but in the end that's only necessary if your `<database>` is very large and the stylesheet becomes sluggish.